# How to use osmocom tcap-map for parsing the ss7-Map data

Tags: c, parsing, github, asn.1, ss7

**Requirement:** Need to parse the buffer which contains SS7-MAP data and return the required structure basis on the type of input data(Need parsers for SS7-MAP in c/c++).

**Actions:** I have installed all the required modules of osmocom(http://cgit.osmocom.org/libosmo-asn1-map/) which uses asn files to generate parsers for SS7-MAP.

**Stuck:** There is no usage of using the module. I don't know how to use the modules to parse the buffer.

Kindly help me out...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been looking through. Hope this can offer you some clues on how to continue investigating. From the headers this seem to be just using [asn1c](http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/) over the ASN.1 files. You might find more information on the runtime required to encode/decode at the asn1c site. The other thing to look for is the starting point. I've seen "TCAP Component" defined, but I haven't been able to find the TCAP Message (Begin/End/Continue/Abort) definition, so that probably means that you would need to start at the Invoke level.... or define them yourself and run the compiler.